# BigQuery Transpose on multiple Columns

Tags: sql, python-3.x, google-bigquery, transpose, bigquery-udf

Need Help with below Transformation in BigQuery,
**Here CMPTTR NAME will increase dynamically from 2 to n**:
[image]

Comment: Please provide some more details and show some work. I guess you want to use `group by` and `Select my_prod_id, any_value(case when substr(CMPTTR_PROD_ID,5,1)="A" then CMPTTR_PROD_ID end) as abc_prod_id FROM your_table group by 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

[image]

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]